# i send mail python to outlook mail (disappear HTML content) like image video

Tags: python-2.7, outlook, mime-types, multipart

i send mail with html content from my python server to outlook but not show html contetnt like image,video (all url is remove) and working fine in gmail,yahoo

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bx7i5tBqPWWWZUpMM3JVajRKdEk/edit?usp=drivesdk

***I send this content in mail***

**Content**

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============2116270645=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
Message-Id: <1419485114.275409936904907.815358991987457-my-private@ppa-desktop>
Subject: demo testing
From: demo@outlook.com
Reply-To: demo@outlook.com
To: demo@outlook.com
Date: Thu, 25 Dec 2014 05:25:14 -0000

--===============2116270645==
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="===============0546854430=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

--===============0546854430==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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--===============0546854430==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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```

**HTML**

```
 <div style="padding:0px; margin:0px">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:10px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top;padding:0px;font-family:arial;font-size:12px;color:rgb(51,51,51)">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:600px" valign="top">
                    <h2 style="text-align: center; padding:0px 5px">A Punchy Headline</h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:600px" valign="top"><img src="/website/static/src/img/big_picture.png" style="display:block;border:none;min-height:250px;margin:0 auto;" width="500"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:600px" valign="top">
                    <p style="text-align: center; overflow:hidden"></p>
                    <h3 style="text-align: center; padding:0px 5px">A Small Subtitle</h3>
                    <p></p>
                    <p style="text-align: center; overflow:hidden">Choose a vibrant image and write an inspiring paragraph about it. It does not have to be long, but it should reinforce your image.</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div style="padding:0px; margin:0px">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:10px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top;padding:0px 5px;font-family:arial;font-size:12px;color:rgb(51,51,51)">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:600px" valign="top">
                    <h2 style="text-align: center">A Great Headline</h2>
                    <h3 style="text-align: center">A good subtitle</h3>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:600px" valign="top">
                    <div style="padding:0px 5px">
                        <p style="overflow:hidden">A great way to catch your reader's attention is to tell a story. Everything you consider writing can be told as a story.</p>
                        <p style="overflow:hidden"><strong>Great stories have personality.</strong> Consider telling a great story that provides personality. Writing a story with personality for potential clients will asist with making a relationship connection. This shows up in small quirks like word choices or phrases. Write from your point of view, not from someone else's experience.</p>
                        <p style="overflow:hidden"><strong>Great stories are for everyone even when only written for just one person.</strong> If you try to write with a wide general audience in mind, your story will ring false and be bland. No one will be interested. Write for one person. If it’s genuine for the one, it’s genuine for the rest.</p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div style="padding:0px; margin:0px">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:10px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top;padding:0px;font-family:arial;font-size:12px;color:rgb(51,51,51)">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:200px" valign="top"><img src="/website/static/src/img/desert_thumb.jpg" style="display:block;border:none;min-height:50px" width="175"></td>
                <td style="width:200px" valign="top"><img src="/website/static/src/img/deers_thumb.jpg" style="display:block;border:none;min-height:50px" width="175"></td>
                <td style="width:200px" valign="top"><img src="/website/static/src/img/china_thumb.jpg" style="display:block;border:none;min-height:50px" width="175"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:200px" valign="top">
                    <h3 style="text-align: center; padding:0px 5px">Feature One</h3>
                    <p style="overflow:hidden">Choose a vibrant image and write an inspiring paragraph about it. It does not have to be long, but it should reinforce your image.</p>
                </td>
                <td style="width:200px" valign="top">
                    <h3 style="text-align: center; padding:0px 5px">Feature Two</h3>
                    <p style="overflow:hidden">Choose a vibrant image and write an inspiring paragraph about it. It does not have to be long, but it should reinforce your image.</p>
                </td>
                <td style="width:200px" valign="top">
                    <h3 style="text-align: center; padding:0px 5px">Feature Three</h3>
                    <p style="overflow:hidden">Choose a vibrant image and write an inspiring paragraph about it. It does not have to be long, but it should reinforce your image.</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You are only sending plain text message, why do you expect any HTML content?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko check it again i send palin text and html both.

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML content? Most people here cannot do base64 decoding off the top of our heads :-) What exactly is not being displayed? Keep in mind that Outlook uses Word, not IE, to display the HTML content, and quite a few things (like scripts) won't work at all.

Comment: hello added html contetn.

Answer (score 0):

You HTML refers to the images using a relative (to the web server root) urls:

```
<img src="/website/static/src/img/big_picture.png"
```

You need either an absolute url or you need to add images as attachments to your message, set their Content-Id MIME headers, and make sure your HTML refers to the images using the src=cird attribute:

```
<img src="cid:Your_Image_Content_Id"
```

Comment: thanks but in html contetn this kind of path 
/web/binary/image?model=pos.category&amp;field=image_medium&amp;id=13" then what can i do ?

Comment: That path is relative to the root (e.g. www.mydomain.com). Outlook obviously has no idea bout where the HTML came from. If you absolutely cannot modify the HTML, you can set the PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_LOCATION property on the attachment to the location (relative or not) of the image, e.g. "/website/static/src/img/big_picture.png"